# C++ how to modify a 2D vector of objects size in a function initialized in the constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

Since I'm Italian, the function names are in Italian but really simple to understand: immagine=image, inserisci=insert, altezza=height, larghezza=width,mosaico =mosaic, righe=rows, colonne=columns.

So this program has 2 classes: an image with its attributes and a mosaic, which contains n images and this is represented through a 2D vector of obj Image (Immagine). The 2D vector has to be initialized in the constructor with r rows and c columns and using the inserisci (insert/add) function will then grow its dimension. Then if the element passed in the insert function has more rows/columns the insert function has to add the needed rows and columns in order to insert the element.

The problem is that even though I used pointers/references, every time I try to insert an element with a size that is bigger than the one initialized in the constructor, it gives me an error, meaning that the 2D vector that I modify in the insert function is not really edited... (look at the main when I insert: m2.inserisci(i4, 4, 4, &m2.immagini) since 4 rows > inital size of rows and same for columns gives me a runnning error..) Hope it is clear. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Immagine{
private:
        string nome;

public:
        int altezza;
        int larghezza;
        Immagine(string,int,int);
        string toString();
};
Immagine::Immagine(string n, int a, int l){
    nome = n;
    altezza = a;
    larghezza= l;
}
string Immagine::toString(){ 
    return nome;
        }

class Mosaico{
public:
    Mosaico(int, int,Immagine,vector< vector<Immagine> >*);

    int getRighe();
    int getColonne();
    string getImmagine(int,int);
    bool exist(int, int);
    Immagine getIm(int,int);
    void inserisci(Immagine,int,int,vector< vector<Immagine> >*);
    vector< vector<Immagine> > immagini;
    vector< vector<Immagine> >* aPointer= &immagini;
};
    Mosaico::Mosaico(int r, int c,Immagine imm, vector< vector<Immagine> >* immag ){
    (*immag).resize(r);
    for(int i=0; i<(*immag).size(); i++)
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
            (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j,imm);
}   
bool Mosaico::exist(int r, int c){
    for(int i = 0; i < getRighe(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<getColonne(); j++){
            if(i==r && j==c && immagini[r][c].toString()!= " "){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }     
    return false;
}
int Mosaico::getRighe(){
    return immagini.size();
    }
int Mosaico::getColonne(){
    return immagini[1].size();
    }
string Mosaico::getImmagine(int r, int c){
    if(exist(r,c))
    return immagini[r][c].toString();
    }
Immagine Mosaico::getIm(int r, int c){
    return immagini[r][c];
}


void Mosaico::inserisci(Immagine imm,int r, int c, vector< vector<Immagine> >* immag){
        if(r<(*immag).size() && c<(*immag)[0].size()){
        (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
        }
        else if(r>=(*immag).size() && c>=(*immag)[0].size()){
            (*immag).resize(r);
            for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
                for(int j=(*immag)[0].size(); j<c; j++){
                    (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j, imm);
                }
            }
            (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
            }
        else if(r>=(*immag).size() && c<(*immag)[0].size()){
            (*immag).resize(r);
            (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
        }
    else if(r<(*immag).size() && c>=(*immag)[0].size()){
            for(int i=0; i<(*immag).size(); i++){
                for(int j=(*immag)[0].size(); j<c; j++){
                    (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j, imm);
                }
            }
            (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
            }

}

int main() {
    Immagine i1 ("I01",300,200);
    Immagine i2 ("I02",300,400);
    Immagine i3 ("I03",400,200);
    Immagine i4 ("I04",400,400);
    cout << "Creo un mosaico 2x2 con quattro immagini" <<endl;
    Mosaico m2(2,2,i1,&m2.immagini) ;
    cout<<m2.getRighe()<<endl;
    cout<<m2.getColonne()<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < m2.getRighe(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < m2.getColonne(); j++){
            //if(m1.exist(i,j))
            cout<<m2.getImmagine(i,j);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    m2.inserisci(i1, 0, 0, &m2.immagini);
    m2.inserisci(i2, 0, 1, &m2.immagini);
    m2.inserisci(i3, 1, 0, &m2.immagini);
    m2.inserisci(i4, 4, 4, &m2.immagini); //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    cout <<"Stampa mosaico: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < m2.getRighe(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < m2.getColonne(); j++){
            cout<<m2.getImmagine(i,j);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

By the way, this was a Java exercise and I tried to do it in C++. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `getColonne(){ return immagini[1].size(); }` is dangerous because you have not made sure that `immagini.size() > 1`

Comment: The `insert` calls look like they could be `push_back`s.

Comment: `getImmagine` is missing a return in the (non-existing) else branch. Please turn on compiler warnings and read them carefully.

Comment: This is an off-by-one, or `<=` vs `<` bug in `inserisci`. For `(*immag)[r][c]=imm;` to be valid, the vectors need to have the sizes `(*immag).size() >= r+1` and `(*immag)[0].size() >= c+1`. However, the loop conditions are `i < r` and `j < c`, the resize uses `(*immag).resize(r)`. This produces vectors of the size `(*immag).size() == r` and `(*immag)[0].size() == c`.

Comment: Oh, and the loop init `int j = (*immag)[0].size()` is fundamentally flawed: This size is changed in the first iteration of the loop, such that no elements are added to any of the other elements of `*immag`. In addition to that, you need to add *more elements* to the vectors created by `(*immag).resize(r)`. The elements which have been in `*immag` prior to the resize have `size() > 0` typically, the new ones have `size() == 0`. This loop init should be `int j = (*immag)[i].size()`.

Comment: thaank you so much!!!! now the program works correctly :) yh about the getColonne() function i didn't see that was 1 instead of 0 :) thanks for everything!!

Answer (score 0):

Before I'll get to the details of the issues, let me first state that there are a lot of things in the code I'd do differently. Most prominently, I'd probably use a flat `vector<Image>` for storage instead of a `vector<vector<..>>`. But such things are better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) in my opinion (once the code is working).

---

The biggest problems in the OP's code are within the implementation of the `inserisci` function:

> ```
> void Mosaico::inserisci(Immagine imm,int r, int c,
>                         vector< vector<Immagine> >* immag) {
>     if(r < (*immag).size() && c < (*immag)[0].size()){
>         (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
>     }
> ```

This part is fine, if we assume that `(*immag)[i].size()` is the same for all `i` in `[0, (*immag).size())`. Let us call this assumption A. The `[x, y)` notation stands for a half-open-on-right interval (x is within that interval, y is not). Note that you can replace `(*e).m` with `e->m`, which I'll do in the following.

The assumption A is a class invariant: after every member function (except for the destructor), this class invariant must hold. Continuing with the `inserisci` function:

> ```
>     else if(r>=(*immag).size() && c>=(*immag)[0].size()){
>         (*immag).resize(r);
> ```

The `*immag` vector now has `r` elements. This is **insufficient** if you want to access the `r`th element, since indexing starts with 0. You need to have at least `r+1` elements. Replace the above `resize` with:

```
        int newRowCount = r+1;
        (*immag).resize(newRowCount);
```

Continuing with the OP's function:

> ```
>         for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
> ```

This has the same off-by-one bug: replace `r` with `newRowCount`, or simply `immag->size()`.

```
         for(int i=0; i<immag->size(); i++){
```

Continuing with the OP's function:

> ```
>             for(int j=(*immag)[0].size(); j<c; j++){
>                 (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j, imm);
>             }
>         }
> ```

With the above `resize`, we have added `newRowCount - immag->size()` new elements to the `immag` vector. Those **new** elements are vectors of the size 0. To be able to access the `c`th element of such a vector, we need to add at least `c+1` elements to it.

The value of `(*immag)[0].size()` however changes after the first iteration of the outer loop such that `(*immag)[0].size() == c` for the remaining `(*immag)[i]` elements where `i` is in `[1, newRowCount)`. This code won't add any new columns to those rows. A simple fix is:

```
            int newColumnCount = c+1;
            for(int j=(*immag)[i].size(); j < newColumnCount; j++){
                (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j, imm);
            }
        }
```

> ```
>         (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
>     }
> ```

A note related to code review: You can very easily resize the inner elements as well, using the resize-overload which takes an additional argument:

```
(*immag)[i].resize(newColumnCount, imm);
```

Continuing with the OP:

> ```
>     else if(r>=(*immag).size() && c<(*immag)[0].size()){
>         (*immag).resize(r);
> ```

This suffers from the same off-by-one bug again. You need to have at least `r+1` elements to access the `r`th element in the following

> ```
>         (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
>     }
> ```

And in the following piece of code, the same issues appear as in the second branch (that is, `(*immag)[0].size()` instead of referring to the current element's size, and `j < c` instead of `j < newColumnCount`).

> ```
>     else if(r<(*immag).size() && c>=(*immag)[0].size()){
>         for(int i=0; i<(*immag).size(); i++){
>             for(int j=(*immag)[0].size(); j<c; j++){
>                 (*immag)[i].insert((*immag)[i].begin()+j, imm);
>             }
>         }
>         (*immag)[r][c]=imm;
>     }
> }
> ```